# Google:assistance the final response did not set

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google

we have Google Assistance project, that is working fine, for every intent, 
now i want to get dynamic data from web service and return, for that, I am using request module, but its giving error

**the final response did not set**

below is my code

```
 app.intent('doctor_list', (conv, {doctor}) => {
  Request.get("url", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
         con.ask('data return')
    }
    con.ask('err')
  });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't clear in what your `Request` object is, but I suspect the problem is that you're not returning a Promise object from your call. Network calls are handled asynchronously in node.js, and when you make an async call, you need to return a Promise object.

The easiest way to handle this is using the [request-promise-native package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native). Your code might look something like this:

```
const Request = require('request-promise-native');
app.intent('doctor_list', (conv,{doctor}) => {
  return Request.get('url')
    .then( body => {
      conv.ask( 'data return' );
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log( err );
      conv.close( 'error' );
    });
});
```